# custom gnu-screen session log filename

Tags: gnu-screen

I'd like to know if someone has tried logging their gnu-screen session to a logfile (other than the default screenlog.N where N is the session number).

I tried doing the following

```
~$ screen -L custom_screenlog -S test_session
```

but screen would terminate. It's not also in the screen manual. Tried searching Google and I can't seem to see an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My 4.0.2 version of GNU screen has no argument to `-L` switch. The log file is systematically named `screenlog.0` and created in the current directory.
Then you may simply try:

```
screen -L -S test_session
```

Edit:
you can customize your `.screenrc` file, adding for instance

```
logfile /tmp/screenlog-%Y%m%d-%c:%s
```

This way log files may be stored in a predefined directory (`/tmp` in this example)
and may be named after logfile opening date

Comment: Is there anywhere that points out the syntax of that `logfile` line? The manpage doesn't appear to have that info…

Comment: To zero-fill the time instead of space-fill: `%0c` instead of `%c`